# JSFORCE: File is not supported message is being shown while downloading file from sfdc rest api and write on local disk

Tags: node.js, rest, salesforce, workbench, jsforce

I have been trying to download image file using JS force for node js and able to create a file on local after retrieving data and converting it to base64 format but image if showing "**file not supported message**" whereas being able to download javascript type of file with correct data.

I am querying the attachment field of knowledge article in salesforce.

Following is my query :

```
SELECT Body__c, Attachment__Name__s, Attachment__ContentType__s, Attachment__Length__s, Attachment__Body__s, Id, KnowledgeArticleId, Title, UrlName FROM Knowledge__kav
```

I am sending GET request to **Attachment__Body__s** field of article.

Following is my node js code:

```
function createFile(attachmentBody,attachmntContentType,attachmntName){
var req = {
url: attachmentBody,
method: 'GET',
headers: {
        "Content-Type": attachmntContentType
        }
    };
            
var test = conn.request(req, function(err, resp) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        } else {
                        
var fileBuffer=Buffer.from(resp, 'binary').toString('base64');
console.log('fileBuffer---  '+ fileBuffer);
fs.writeFile('./downloadedAttachments/'+attachmntName,fileBuffer,'base64', function(err){
    if (err) throw err
        console.log('File saved.')
        })
            
    }
});
}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am successfully able to download the file in the correct format. following is my updated code :

```js
function createFile(knbid,attachmntName,callback) {
                    
            
        var file_here = conn.sobject('Knowledge__kav').record(knbid);
        
        file_here.retrieve(function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
            callback(0)
            } else {
                
                var obj = fs.createWriteStream('./downloadedAttachments/'+attachmntName, {defaultEncoding: 'binary'})
                //console.log('blob--'+JSON.stringify(file_here.blob('Attachment__Body__s')));
                var stream = file_here.blob('Attachment__Body__s').pipe(obj);
            
                stream.on('finish', function (err, result) {
                
                    if (err)
                    console.log('not downloaded'+knbid);
                    else
                    console.log('downloaded-'+knbid);
                    
                })
            }
        });
        }
```